# .Net 4 - Console App - Problems with full trust application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, security, .net-assembly

I got the following exception, while trying to load a assembly in runtime using this command:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyFilePath);
```

> System.Security.SecurityException: 'Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.'

**Some info about my app:**

1. Is a Console Application, c#, .net 4.6;
2. Is a Signed Assembly;
3. I already tried to sign the assembly that I'm loading, but nothing changed.
4. Already tried to Check Enable ClickOnce Security settings (full trust).

**Questions:**

1. What can I do so my assembly have the correct permissions to load this other assembly?
2. Are there any other setting I can do to give FULL TRUST to this assembly?

Thanks.
Conan.

Comment: Are you running from an administrator console?  It might be an OS-level security issue rather than an app-level one.

Comment: Merely that piece of code won't trigger the exception easily. You have to provide more information (a complete sample to reproduce the issue everywhere).

Comment: You need to document exactly where the .exe is stored.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers. I found out what my problem was.

Sorry for the lack of details. I totally forgotten that this part of my application run's in a separated App Domain. The main app has full access, but the new App Domain was not getting the correct permissions. After I gave full access on the AppDomain creation, everything worked well.